# ASP.NET Identity with MySQL Provider on production server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have set up ASP.NET Identity with MySQL Provider according to this two guides: [Asp.NET](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) and [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w).
I use EntityFramework and ADO.NET to access to other tables in database and have one connection string for this. The other connection string (DefaultConnection) is for Identity.
I have two different databases - one for development and one for production. Firs is on my local computer, the other is on Amazone server.

This is how my web.config looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Database=[DB_NAME];Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=[DB_PASS]" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="AdoNetConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HealthModel.csdl|res://*/HealthModel.ssdl|res://*/HealthModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;database=[DB_NAME];server=localhost;user id=root;password=[DB_PASS]&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Web.Release.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection"
     connectionString="Database=[DB_NAME];Data Source=[DB_SERVER];User Id=[DB_USER];Password=[DB_PASS]" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
     xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
<add name="AdoNetConnection"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/HealthModel.csdl|res://*/HealthModel.ssdl|res://*/HealthModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=[DB_SERVER];user id=[DB_USER];password=[DB_PASS];persistsecurityinfo=True;database=[DB_NAME];" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
     xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I build and run application in debug, everything is great. I can access to other data tables from database and also to identity data tables to register a new user. If tables don't exist, they are automatically created (migration). 
But when I publish it to Azure in Release mode, there comes a problem. I can still access to the other data tables, but I can not register new user. Actually, everything goes ok when registering, but user does not show up in database - in table aspnetusers. Data tables for Identity, including aspnetusers are not even created, although they are not here. 
As I said, I look in development database in debug mode and in release database in release mode.

Could please anyone help me to figure out, where is a problem? Thank you very much!